# Windows phone 8.1 BackButton Navigation issue

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am developing Windows phone 8.1 Silver Light Application. In the application there are so many screens. Pages are navigating perfectly.

My issue is when i press on back button(Windows Phone Back Button) The pages are going back to the previous pages. I want to stop back button navigation in my application. I followed below link but i am not succeeded.
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-us/131a99ce-53a4-4389-81e9-7801af57b78b/used-hardwarebuttonsbackpressed-handler

Could any one advise me.

Comment: Beware, it can be the reason to fail the certification in the store.

Comment: Means if i add below code windows store accepts my application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this for back button on your XAML.cs page :

```
protected override void OnBackKeyPress(System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
{
        base.OnBackKeyPress(e);
        if (NavigationService.CanGoBack)
        {
            while (NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry() != null)
            {
                NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
            }
        }
 }
```

Comment: The above code will terminates the application,it cannot hold the screen.

Comment: Above code is for permanent back from app to phone main screen.